# PDO Exception "Could not find driver" (pgsql)

Tags: php, windows, pdo

I downloaded and installed PostgreSQL 9.2.3, which came with Stackbuilder.

I used the PostgreSQL Stackbuilder to install Apache (2.2.22) & PHP (5.4.5).

Now I'm trying to connect to a database with PDO, but I'm getting a `driver not found` error.

I've un-commented the `extension=php_pgsql.dll` & `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in my php.ini file.

My phpinfo(); function shows that they're enabled.
[image]

The main thing I'm noticing is that within my **php\** directory there's no **ext\** directory with these files.  I would have assumed that these files would have been automatically installed to a **php\** subdirectory.

Where could these extensions be stored; do I need to designate an absolute path for php to find them?

**UPDATE:**
So I went into php.ini and turned on Startup Errors.  When I launch the commandline php.exe I get errors stating that php_pgsql.dll & php_pdo_pgsql.dll can't be found.

[image]
It looks like they're trying to reference them on a D: drive, which I don't have.  I installed everything to the same directory on the E: drive.  I can't find the extensions anywhere (and neither can php).

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I have defined constants in a configuration file.  If i echo it back it looks like this: `"pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;user=postgres;password=postgres;dbname=Test"`

Comment: That looks like a path from the build server, rather than one that'd ever get installed on your local system. Weird. Where's `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` on your system? Is it or the folder it's in listed in `php.ini` anywhere? or on the `PATH`?

Comment: The folder listed in `php.ini` is just `extension_dir = "ext"`.  The directory is buried in `php\SDK\include\ext\pdo`, which only contains two files `php_pdo.h` & `php_pdo_driver.h`.  I also tried appending my php directory to my `Sys PATH` without any luck.

Comment: I wound up installing WAMP then put postgres on top of it, which I got to work.

Answer (score 4):

In Wamp (windows)...

copy `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.xx\libpq.dll`

paste in `C:\Windows\System32\`

Comment: Please add some explanation for this.

Answer (score 3):

on Wamp, there are 2 php.ini files, you will have to check if  the Postgresql extension is on both!
The extension line is

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

So check on

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
```

Also check on

```
C:\wamp\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
```

After adding the extension line, restart Apache and it will work.